# jQuery Validate remote option with path parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

A field in one of my forms does a remote call to validate availability of a name. By default, the validation plugin wants to use GET, and appends a query string with a key of the field name and a value of the field value.

You can override this by changing to POST and setting a data value.

However, in both cases, the URL itself is expected to be static. For example, but default you don't need more than this:

```
remote: {
  url: '/validationService'
}
```

Which will do a GET to `/validationService?fieldname=fieldvalue`

Since "remote" is an initialization-time parameter, you can't typically use a dynamic URL. I tried putting in a function expression and it just stringified it rather than evaluating it.

**The problem**

I need it to be dynamic. The value of the field is passed as a path parameter. In other words, When the validation is fired, it would send a request to:

```
validationService/fieldvalue
```

(don't worry, the validationService can ONLY process that particular field, so there is no need to specify fieldname anywhere) There is no POST or accompanying payload, and although it is a GET, there is no query string.

Any idea how I might accomplish this? (dynamically-evaluated URL based on field's current value at validation time)

---

**Additional Details**

The validation service returns JSON formatted thus:

```
{
  comment: "Success OR error message",
  isValid: true
}
```

So, to know if it was successful or not, I need to get the message (which as far as I can tell is an async operation) and then evaluate the "isValid" parameter. Ideally, I would also throw the comment as the "message".

---

**Update 2**

I managed to convince the back end to just update the service so that it can accept a query string and operate in its expected way. This has held a new problem, but that can go to another question. I normally wouldn't mind continuing to be the "test subject" for further research (in case anybody else has a problem like my original one) but I'm not set up for running two separate environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the custom method (provided by the plugin)(http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod) that delegates to the remote method, and add a class selector that matching that method.

```
<input class="dynamicurl" />

$.validator.addMethod("dynamicurl", function(value, element) {
  return $.validator.methods.remote.call(this, value, element, "http://yoururl/validationService/"+value);
}, $.validator.messages.remote);
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks Vishnu. It definitely starts me on the right path. I will have to research how to use the remote.call, though; I need to further evaluate the returned message to decide if it is a pass or not. I will update the original question with details I didn't know would be relevant.

Comment: I suppose I could implement my own Ajax call and make it blocking. I hate forcing sync, but it would be a solution. The current one is indeed making a call, and I am expecting it to be considered in "error" until I can resolve; in the meantime, it's strange... while typing into the field it remains highlighted but the error message goes away. On blur, the error message appears. I suspect their custom method is slightly flawed, but it could be me.

Comment: (note: the synchronous call worked. Hope the UI isn't sketchy under latency!)

Comment: I tried with ajax call. But its returning even before ajax returns response, even though I have kept it async :false. Any idea why it would be happening?

Comment: @GregPettit Is my solution worked for you? Or still, you need any assistance with that?